# GeoServer 2.21.1 - Does it work with JDK 17 or 19?

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to install GeoServer v2.21.1 on a server where I've JDK 19 binaries available, but it's not allowing me to proceed for installation. I can see on installer where it says it requires JDK/JRE version 8 or 11 only, but is there any upcoming version of GeoServer planned to use JDK 17 or 19 or I'm completely missing something where existing GeoServer 2.21.1 can be installed with JDK 17/19?

[image]

Comment: Geoserver docs point to https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11

Answer (score 3):

GeoServer 2.21.1 works *experimentally* on Java 17, higher versions are not tested.

The Windows installer might have extra restrictions, it seems to be checking specifically for 1.8 or 11: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/release/installer/win/build/geoserver_winsetup.nsi#L420

For a production system I would recommended to install Tomcat first, and deploy the GeoServer inside of it anyways. The installer comes with a minified version of Jetty, that's meant to be easy but not specifically tuned from production.